# Replace video track in MKV with track from different MKV file

Tags: video, batch, video-editing, matroska

I have two MKV files with the same movie and I want to replace video track in the first file with video track from the second file, using commandline (so it can be used again with different pair of MKV files).

It's important that I want to keep all attachments, audio tracks, chapters etc in first MKV unchanged. This is why, if possible, I don't want to extract everything from first file and then mux everything again with only video track changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following command seems to do the thing:

```
mkvmerge -o "merged.mkv" -D ( "first.mkv" ) -A -S -T -M -B --no-chapters ( "second.mkv" )
```

It takes everything except the video (`-D`) from the `first.mkv` and only video (`-A -S -T -M -B` disables audio, subtitles, tags, attachments and buttons) from `second.mkv`.

Answer (score 1):

@lort: thanks a lot.
Adding a loop to your code

```
for %%x in (firstFolder/*.mkv) do "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "newFolder\%%~x" -D ( "firstFolder\%%~x" ) -A -S -T -M -B --no-chapters ( "secondFolder\%%~x" )
```

Working structure:

- firstFolder: the folder with movies that have all tracks to be copied (besides the video track)
- secondFolder: the folder with movies that have the video track to be copied
- newFolder: the one that will get the merged movies

The batch file is inside the parent folder that have all the three folders.